# Can we create our own date format in Java?

Tags: java

I need to format a date(yyyyMMDD) into YYYY-MM-DD. Can I create a date format of the latter ?

Comment: Note that `YYYY` is an invalid format and that `DD` stands for "day in year" not "day in month" as you seem to initially expect (which would then be `dd`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String sourceDateStr = "20101012";
    try {
        Date sourceDate = sourceFormat.parse(sourceDateStr);

        String targetDateStr = targetFormat.format(sourceDate);

        System.out.println(targetDateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Gives the output `2010-01-12`

Comment: I'm more than slightly embaressed I didn't spot it in the first place :(

Answer (score 10):

Yes.
Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-written class like the pojava http://www.pojava.org/ for this.
It's very good a recognising different date formats and translating between them.

For example, to translate between the formats above:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Date:" + new DateTime("Date").toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
} catch (Exception error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
}
```

I find that using this class helps as I don't have to worry too much about the different date formats that exist out there (except between UK/US dd/MM/yyyy & MM/dd/yyyy, which you can specifically configure the class for)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at joda-time: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/